# MaskedTextField with mask overwrites characters to the right, how can I prevent this?

Tags: office-ui-fabric-react, fluent-ui

If I type `12345` and set the cursor between 3 and 4 and start typing this will overwrite the 4 and 5. What I want is to be able to eg. add 77 inbetween and the output will be: `123 774 5`. Is there any way I can do this?

My code is essentially just:

```
<MaskedTextField
    label="With input mask"
    mask="999 999 999"
    maskChar=""
/>
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-sunset-khegc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem. Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: Not yet. I opened this issue at fluent UI: https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/14752

Comment: Seems like no luck with resolving this?